# Is it possible to use Firebase Auth to secure my Google Cloud Endpoints API?

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, google-cloud-endpoints, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I plan to make an API from my GAE app by using the Google cloud endpoints.

I'd like to make this API available for third devs, so that they can make some requests on my endpoints.

However, i'd like to secure all this and limit the access only to some parts of the API and only allow some operations.

it seems firebase authentication is designed to manage the access to the server.

But i can't understand if i can secure my Google cloud endpoints with the Firebase Server SDK.

In other words, does the Firebase server SDK only designed to work with The firebase Database or it's possible to make it work with Google cloud endpoints ?

I just give you an example of what i'm expecting from Firebase + GCE.

1. I want to open my backend to third persons.
2. I want to set up a kind of scope (using firebase if possible).
3. The scope should define which operations will be allowed to be done throught my public GCE API. For ex. to open my backend at 10% but 90% remains closed and private.
4. Then, my application should be able to generate an auth token each time it will be demanded by the third dev. The token is for authentication purpose.
5. Once authenticated, the third dev can use my API and make allowed requests.

So, can i set up such a thing with firebase and GCE (Google Cloud endpoints) ?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to do so.

There are several ways to achieve the same. Google Cloud Endpoints authentication can be done in the following ways

- Firebase authentication
- Auth0
- Google Authentication (by signing into google account)
- Custom authentication methods.

You can follow the [link](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/authenticating-users) for more details.

I had faced some issues while doing the same, please follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45104090/android-firebase-auth-for-cloud-end-point-not-working/45145556#45145556)